# Event Scheduler not working

Tags: mysql

`create event del 
on schedule 
every 5 minute 
starts
'2012-11-16 10:20:23'
do
delete from purchased limit 1;`

As per my above query every 5 minutes 1 row from the table purchased should be deleted but, this event gives no result

Comment: If you execute this in the shell do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: No i don't get any warning or error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **event_scheduler** variable to ON state. 
Run this statement:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 'ON'
```

Or Update **my.ini** file:

```
event_scheduler=ON
```